# Toggle class on all elements EXCEPT on that's hovered jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I would like to add a class to all the elements in my menu that ARE NOT being hovered over. Instead of

```
$('#nav li').hover(function(){$('ul',this).toggleClass('active')
```

I would like all the other elements in the unordered list to be changed.  Any simple way?

HTML

```
       <ul>
<li><a href="statelevel.html">State Level</a></li>
<li><a href="nationallevel.html">National Level</a></li>
<li><a href="resourcesbycoutny2.html">Community Level</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li> <a href="research.html">Research</a></li>

<li> <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you please post your HTML? It is not clear which element is hovered and for which elements the class should be changed. We need to know the relationship between the elements.

Comment: okey doke. do you need more than that?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#nav li').hover(function(){$('ul',this).not($(this)).addClass('blah')
```